# How to render template into an outlet from another template

Tags: ember.js

My application will have a sidebar that has content which changes depending on the current route. So, if someone visits `account`, the content on the sidebar will be different than if someone visits `members`.

I've attempted to do this with the `accounts` route, but I'm running into issues. I'm using this code

```
Dashboard.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        renderTemplate: function() {
                this.render('account_choices', {
                        outlet: 'choices',
                        into: 'sidebar'
                })
        }
});
```

My `application` template is:

```
{{render header}}

{{render sidebar}}

<div id="outlet" class="main">
        {{outlet}}
</div>
```

and my `sidebar` template is:

```
<div class="sidebar">
        {{outlet choices}}
</div>
```

But it won't render `account_choices` into the outlet `choices` in the `sidebar` template. It also produces the error `Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'connectOutlet' of undefined`.

How can I render the `account_choices` template into the `choices` outlet in `sidebar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little difficult to explain, but the entire path is hooked up up front and the named outlet `sidebar` doesn't exist until they are rendered.  Fortunately you can just hook up a render later in the run loop, and the `dynamic named outlet` will exist by then.

```
renderTemplate: function() {
  var self = this;
  Em.run.later(function(){
    self.render('account_choices', {
      outlet: 'choices',
      into: 'sidebar'
    });
  });
 }
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/azimigEF/1/edit

Comment: In the `renderTemplate` hook of `sidebar` or `account`?

Comment: I just tried it, and it works, but only when I go to that route. When I am on that route and refresh, meaning I visit `/accounts` directly, it fails with that error message.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I think you've answered almost every Ember question I've had, so thanks for that as well. :-)